# Is it correct to evaluate a classifier on cross_val_predict output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I have some classifiers. I want to get the metrics for the classifier with [`classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)

I used [`cross_val_predict`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) to get the predictions, and then passed them to `classification_report`.
I also use the output of `cross_val_predict` to plot the confusion matrix.

```
labels = get_labels() #ground truth
result = cross_val_predict(classifier, features, labels, cv=KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed))
report = classification_report(labels, result, digits=3, target_names=['no', 'yes'], output_dict=True)
cm = confusion_matrix(result, labels, [no, yes])
```

In the `cross_val_predict` documentation:

> Passing these predictions into an evaluation metric may not be a valid way to measure generalization performance. Results can differ from cross_validate and cross_val_score unless all tests sets have equal size and the metric decomposes over samples.

So, is it the wrong way to do that? How should I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your process should look something like this:

1. Train/test split
2. Model selection using a (cross-)validation set
3. Retrain your model using the whole train set
4. Evaluate on your test split from step 1

If you do not have a lot of data, training with KFold should give you more reliable results than a single train/test split but as a rule of thumb, consider that you should evaluate on a dataset/split that has not been used before, even if it was only used for model selection or early stopping.

Back to your question, `cross_val_predict` is actually splitting the input array in `K` splits and using all trained CV models to predict 5 predictions splits, then combined together. I think that you can use that to get a general idea of the cross-validation results (eg if you want to plot them or to calculate additional metrics) but definitely not to evaluate your model.